# InfoPath 2010 repeating section control missing from toolbox

Tags: infopath2010

I inherited an InfoPath 2010 form from someone and wanted to add a repeating section control (so they can add a number of hyperlinks), but it's not in the toolbox. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you created list or document library

Comment: It seems that the form is based on a list and therefore any repeating tools are not available.

Comment: Yes You create the document library for getting Reapting table.